# Doors DXL filter ,

Tags: ibm-doors

I have the following snip of dxl code, 
I would like to copy the object ID with the filter F3 is on. :
I dont know what I am doing wrong it gives me (ID) of all the object.

```
string Id
int x=0;
int y=0;
Id = o."SourceID"

Filter f0 = hasNoLinks(linkFilterIncoming, "*")
Filter f1=attribute "_TraceTo" == "System"
Filter f2 = attribute "Object Type" == "requirement" 
Filter f3 = f1&&f2&&f0
addFilter(m,f3,x,y)
print x ":\t" fullName(module(m)) "\n" 
wOutKLHUntraced << Id "\t" fullName(module(m)) "\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to add the statement `filtering on` after adding the filter, so that the filter is applied. Then the filtered objects will be the only ones visible.

Then, you set "Id" way too early in the script. At line 4, "o" is set to
    some object, I don't know which one, but certainly not the result of
    your filter. Instead, after the statement `filtering on`, add statements

```
Object o = first m // the first object that is now visible
Id = o."SourceID"
```

Comment: hi , My Script is running good, but Always five different result : as I am running this script in a for loop for around 30 module :

Answer (score 0):

My Script is running good, but gives different results : as I am running this script in a for loop for around 30 module : 
Am I am setting somewhere wrong filters ?

```
Stream TbdUntraced;
     string s
      string d
      Object o
      string trac
      int numReqs = 0;


      string IdNum
      string untraced


      int x=0;
      int y=0;
      int a =0;


       for o in m do
      {
        ensureInLinkedModulesLoaded(o,S_SATISFIES );
        s = o."Object Type"


        string Id
        string Topic
        Topic = o."_Topic"

          numReqs++;




                Filter f0 = hasNoLinks(linkFilterIncoming, "*")
                Filter f1 = contains(attribute "_TraceTo", "TBD", false)            
                Filter f2 = attribute "Object Type" == "requirement" 
                Filter f3 = attribute "MMS5-Autoliv_Supplier_Status" == "agreed"
                Filter f4 = attribute "MMS5-Autoliv_Supplier_Status" == "partly agreed"
                Filter f7 = f0&&f2&&(f3||f4)&&f1
                addFilter(m,f7,x,y)
                filtering on
                d = o."MMS5-Autoliv_OEM_Status"
                Id = o."SourceID"
                Topic = o."_Topic"              
                print x ":\t" name(module(m)) "\n" 
                TbdUntraced << Id "\t" Topic "\t"name(module(m)) "\n"

      }
```